# Recursively scan directory structure with PHP ( dirs only ) and load it into an array

Tags: php, directory, structure

I'm trying to recursively scan the directory structure of my server ( starting from DOCUMENT ROOT ), load the contents into an array ( every subdirectory as a different value ) and output it.

I don't need the files to be present into the array - only the directory structure, nothing else.

For instance:

```
[0] => dir 1
[1] => dir 1/subdir 1
[2] => dir 2
```

and so on.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: [theres some built in goodness to handle that](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: I saw that, but how do I use it to exclude the files from the array?

Comment: are you looking to exclude certain files from the listing or are you concerned that the DirectoryIterator is going to open all the files?

Comment: oh dang, i misread what you were asking for. hold up

Comment: I literally don't want to list any of the files - I only need the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

To recurse through a directory and list only files using the built-in iterator, you'll need to perform a few checks on the way.

The examples [located here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) provide a good amount of base code to build on. But this here should be what you're looking for.

[Having said that, it would be irresponsible not to point out that your question is not considered a good question by StackOverflow standards.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) In the future, do not be surprised if questions as terse as this are downvoted and marked to be closed.

```
<?php

$directory = '.';

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$dirs = array();

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    $filename = $file->getFilename();
    // remove this and check out what happens
    if ($filename == '.' || $filename == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    if ($file->isDir()){
        $dirs[] = $file->getPathname();
    }
}

var_dump($dirs);
```

Comment: The code you have provided works like a charm! One thing though - when I view the array, the entries inside are presented as [0] => string(35) "/home/chalouco/public_html/wp-admin" - why is that?

Comment: The listed directories are absolute paths from the root of the filesystem.

Comment: Yes, I know - I set up Document Root to be the source folder. I mean what are those "string(number)" thingies in the array values?

Comment: thats an effect of `var_dump()`. it tells you the var type and length.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And the help!